# Bootstrap - 404 File not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, widget

When I debug my site, google chrome says this:

```
GET http://localhost/index.php/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js 404 (Not Found) localhost:247
GET http://localhost/index.php/js/main.js 404 (Not Found)
```

As I understand, it can't find these two files. But I never asked it to find them. Here are the headers of my html file:

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    
    <link href="/jquery_ui/development-bundle/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/jquery_ui/development-bundle/themes/smoothnes-edit/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <!--<link href="/jquery_ui/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
    <script src="/jquery_ui/js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="/jquery_ui/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 60px;
            padding-bottom: 40px;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/main.css">

    <script src="/bootstrap/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- LOADING CUSTOMS -->
    
    <?php require('application/views/wqWidgets.php'); ?>
    
    <link href="/Styles/buttons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
    <link href="/Styles/colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/result.js"></script>
    
    <script src="/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
```

I do have some other frameworks as jqwidgets and jquery-ui, and these won't work until this error is fixed. Yes, I have checked if all the links work, and they do.

What is going on, could it be the order?

EDIT:
Full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        
        <link href="/jquery_ui/development-bundle/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/jquery_ui/development-bundle/themes/smoothnes-edit/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet">
        
        <!--<link href="/jquery_ui/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
        <script src="/jquery_ui/js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
        <script src="/jquery_ui/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <style>
            body {
                padding-top: 60px;
                padding-bottom: 40px;
            }
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/main.css">

        <script src="/bootstrap/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
        
        <!-- LOADING CUSTOMS -->
        
        <link rel="stylesheet"        href="/JQWidgets/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"        href="/JQWidgets/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.fresh.css" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQWidgets/scripts/gettheme.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxdatetimeinput.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxcalendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxtooltip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQWidgets/jqwidgets/globalization/jquery.global.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxradiobutton.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxprogressbar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxcheckbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxcombobox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxdropdownlist.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxpanel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxlistmenu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxdata.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxchart.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQWidgets/scripts/json2.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQWidgets/scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxmenu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.selection.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.edit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxknockout.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxdata.export.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.export.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxtree.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxsplitter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxpanel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.sort.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.pager.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JQWidgets/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.selection.js"></script> 
        
        <link href="/Styles/buttons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        
        <link href="/Styles/colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/result.js"></script>
        
        <script src="/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="chromeframe">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">activate Google Chrome Frame</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="brand" href="#">Utoping</a>
                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="active" ><a href="/index.php/">Home</a></li>
                            <li  ><a href="/index.php/about/">About</a></li>
                            <li  ><a href="/index.php/contact/">Contact</a></li>
                            
                                                    </ul>
                        <form class="navbar-form pull-right">
                            <input class="span2" type="text" placeholder="Email">
                            <input class="span2" type="password" placeholder="Password">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
                        </form>
                    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container"><!-- Main hero unit for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
<div class="hero-unit">
    <h1>Utoping</h1>
    <p>Virtual Connection. Achieving Perfection!</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="/index.php/about/">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
</div>

<!-- Example row of columns -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4">
        <h2>Diversity</h2>
        <p>Blablabla...</p>
        <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <h2>Integrity</h2>
        <p>Blablabla...</p>
        <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
   </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <h2>Creativity</h2>
        <p>Blablabla...</p>
        <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="register-unit" class="hero-unit-register">
    <h1><a id="clickme">Register</a></h1>
    <p>Virtual Connection. Achieving Perfection!</p>
    
        <label for="_Email">Email</label>
        <input style='margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 10px;' type="email" name="_Email" id="_Email" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
        
        </br>
        
        <label for="_Nickname">Company Name</label>
        <input style='margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 10px;' type="text" name="_Nickname" id="_Nickname" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
        
        </br>
        
        <select style='visibility: hidden' id='select'>
            <option>Primary</option>
            <option>Secundary</option>
            <option>Tertiary</option>
        </select>
        
        <label for="jqxIndustry">Industry</label>
        <div style='margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 10px;' id='jqxIndustry'></div>
        <input type="hidden" id="Industry" name="Industry">
        
        </br>
        
        <label for="jqxDateTimeInput" title="NOTE: Please change this date, or else the chosen date will be invalid!">Date of creation</label>
        <div style='margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 10px;' id='jqxDateTimeInput'></div>
        <input type="hidden" id="date" name="date">
        
        </br>
        
        <label for="_Password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="_Password" name="_Password" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        
        </br>
        
        <label for="pr" title="For your security, we ask you to repeat your password">Repeat:</label>
        <input type="password" id="pr" name="pr" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        
       </br>
        
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Register Now &raquo;</a></p>
</div>

<script>
var toggle_ = [];
$(document).ready(function () {
    toggle_.toggled = false;
    
    $('#clickme').click(function() {
        if (toggle_.toggled)
        {
            $('#register-unit').animate({
                bottom: '-=200',
              }, 2000, function() {
                // Animation complete.
              });
        }
        else
        {
            $('#register-unit').animate({
                bottom: '+=200',
              }, 2000, function() {
                // Animation complete.
              });
        }
        
        {if (toggle_.toggled){toggle_.toggled = false;}else{toggle_.toggled = true;}}
    });
                    
    $( document ).tooltip();
    
    // JQ WIDGETS
    
    var theme = getTheme();
    
    //JQX
    $("#jqxDateTimeInput").jqxDateTimeInput({ animationType: 'fade', height: '25px', theme: theme });

    $("#jqxIndustry").jqxDropDownList({ animationType: 'fade', width: "510px", height: '25px', theme: theme });
    // Load the data from the Select html element.
    $("#jqxIndustry").jqxDropDownList('loadFromSelect', 'select');

    $("#jqxDateTimeInput").bind('valuechanged', function (event) {
        var date = event.args.date;
        var hiddenField = document.getElementById('date');
        
        hiddenField.value = date;
    });
    
    $('#jqxIndustry').bind('select', function (event) {
        var args = event.args;
        var item = $('#jqxIndustry').jqxDropDownList('getItem', args.index);
        if (item != null) {
            var hiddenField = document.getElementById('Industry');
            hiddenField.value = item.label;
        }
    });
    
    $('#jqxIndustry').bind('unselect', function (event) {
        var args = event.args;
        var item = $('#jqxIndustry').jqxDropDownList('getItem', args.index);
    });
});
</script>
    
<div class="container">         <hr>

            <footer>
                <p>&copy; Vinci Enterprise 2012</p>
            </footer>

        </div> <!-- /container -->

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

        <script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/main.js"></script>

        <script>
            var _gaq=[['_setAccount','UA-XXXXX-X'],['_trackPageview']];
            (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
            g.src=('https:'==location.protocol?'//ssl':'//www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what does your url look like?

Comment: Where do you include `bootstrap.min.js`?

Comment: You're obviously showing us a PHP source file (`<?php require('application/views/wqWidgets.php'); ?>`) and bootstrap is probably included later - please provide the rendered HTML or the full source PHP code... CSS can be included from other places than the HEAD section!

Comment: What's inside `application/views/wqWidgets.php`?

Comment: Plus: `I do have some other frameworks as jqwidgets and jquery-ui, and these won't work until this error is fixed, and yes i have cheched if all the links work, and they do!` : I can't see the link - 404's won't  prevent script execution!!

Comment: You are linking to that many script files!!!!

Comment: You obviously have some kind of a rewrite system which bootstraps all requests to `index.php` and since you obviously do have requests for both of the files you named your requests are rewritten to look like that. Alter your rewrite rules to apply only to non-existing files.

Comment: or exclude js and css extensions from rewrite...also image extensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very bottom bootstrap is requesting these files (just above the Google analytics code):

```
<script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```